# How to change bottom line color of material better spinner?

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to change bottom line color of below MaterialBetterSpinner Spinner please help..

```
<com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
                        android:id="@+id/spUserType"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:hint="Select a Option"
                        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                        app:met_floatingLabel="normal"
                        app:met_textColorHint="#757575"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
styles.xml

<style name="ThemeSpinner">
    <!-- Color when pressed -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#ffa000</item>
    <!-- Default color for the dropdown arrow and line -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#ffc107</item>
</style>
layout.xml

<Spinner
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeSpinner" />
```

Comment: your answer is related to normal spinner so please try to explain related answer to MaterialBetterSpinner.